# Autowried in hibernate constraintvalidator returns nullexception

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-validator

After looking around, I couldn't find any good solution to this.

My autowired didn't work as expected where it returns null. I've autowired this particular class in other classes and it works so it only doesn't work in constraintvalidator classes.

Error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> com.Alex.Mains.JpaApplication.main(JpaApplication.java:21)
> ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
> commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
> transaction   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:543)
> ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
> ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
> ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:632)
> ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386)
> ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
> ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
> ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
> ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
> ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
> com.Alex.Mains.UserRepositoryCommandLineRunner.run(UserRepositoryCommandLineRunner.java:26)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]    ... 5 common frames
> omitted Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while
> committing the transaction    at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
> ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]     ... 21 common frames
> omitted Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028:
> Unexpected exception during isValid call.     at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:186)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:62)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:172)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:116)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:227)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:100)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1360)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:451)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3210)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2378)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]   ... 22 common frames
> omitted Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at
> com.Alex.Validations.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:26)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.Alex.Validations.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:1)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:180)
> ~[hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]

UserService class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRep;
    
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userRep.save(user);
    }
    
    
    public void deleteUser(long userId) {
        userRep.deleteById(userId);
    }
    
    public List<User> retrieveAllUsers(){
        Iterable<User>temp =userRep.findAll();
        List<User>allUsers = null;
        temp.forEach(allUsers::add);
        return allUsers;
    }
    
    public boolean searchByEmail(String email) {
        return userRep.findByEmail(email);
    }
    
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userRep.save(user);
    }
}
```

Annotation interface class

```
 @Target(ElementType.FIELD) 
    //When will the annotation be processed compilation, runtime etc
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    //Where is the logic
    @Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
    @Documented
    public @interface ValidEmail {
        
        //Error message
        String message() default "Invalid email";
        //Required for annotation
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
        
    }
```

Annotation logic class

```
public class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    //Actual place to place the logic to check if the data is valid or not
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (email == null) {
        return false;
        }
        
        List<User> users = service.retrieveAllUsers();
        if (users.size() > 0) { 
        return Pattern.matches("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])", email)
                && service.searchByEmail(email);
        }
        
        else {
            return Pattern.matches("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])", email);
        }
        }
        
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidEmail validEmail) {
        validEmail.message();
    }

}
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.Alex.Mains", "com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights", "com.Alex.Security"
})
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"})
public class JpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }
    
//  @Bean
//  public Validator validator(final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
//
//      ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
//              .configure()
//              .constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(beanFactory))
//              .buildValidatorFactory();
//
//      return validatorFactory.getValidator();
//  }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code for your implementation of the UserService?

Comment: @gaetanTEMATE added

Comment: Show us your packet structure please including where userService and EmailValidator are located as well as the class containing ComponentScan or @SpringBootConfiguration

Comment: @DanielJacob added

Comment: Show me JpaApplication.Java

Comment: @DanielJacob It's in the post

Comment: @DanielJacob You can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is calling the validation and it does not know anything about Spring by default so that `@Autowired` stereotype is not going to be honoured.

If you want to use Spring there, you need to configure Hibernate to be able to resolve the dependency injection properly.

I can't know for sure as you haven't shared a sample we can run but try to add the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
class HibernateCustomization {

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(ValidatorFactory validatorFactory) {
        return (properties) -> {
            properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.JPA_VALIDATION_FACTORY, validatorFactory);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error still, what do you mean by sample run? I just pressed run to get its started

Comment: He is using Spring Boot zo Hibernate is configured automatically. I don’t think that should be the issue.